# Isolating topbar css style from sidebar css style code

Tags: html, css

I have a topbar that works well on all page, and I'm trying to add a sidebar as well, but the style of the topbar is applied to the sidebar instead of using the rest of the code.

How can I isolate topbar css style code portion from the sidebar style css code portion?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <title>
        {% block title %} {% endblock title %}
    </title>
</head>

<body>
  
<!-- Topbar code start -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('routes.dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('routes.portfolio_data_entry') }}">Portfolio Data Entry</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('routes.portfolio_data_entry_dashboard') }}">Portfolio Data Entry Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('routes.stock') }}">Stock</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('routes.account_page') }}">Account</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('routes.logout') }}">Log Out</a>
      </li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('routes.login') }}">Home</a>
      </li>    
      {% endif %}        
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Topbar code end -->

<!-- Sidebar code start end -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand d-flex flex-column align-item-start" id="sidebar">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand text-light mt-5">
            <div class="display-5 font-weight-bold">THANOS</div>
        </a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-column mt-5 w-100">
            <li class="nav-item w-100">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-light pl-4">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item w-100">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-light pl-4">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item w-100">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-light pl-4">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown w-100">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-light pl-4" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Service</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item text-light pl-4 p-2">Service 01</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item text-light pl-4 p-2">Service 02</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item text-light pl-4 p-2">Service 03</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item w-100">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-light pl-4">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="p-4 my-container">
        <button class="btn my-4" id="menu-btn">Toggle Sidebar</button>
        <h1>Sidebar Navigation</h1>
        <p class="text-dark">Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p class="text-dark">Lorem ipsum</p>
    </section>

    <!-- custom js start -->
    <script>
        var menu_btn = document.querySelector("#menu-btn")
        var sidebar = document.querySelector("#sidebar")
        var container = document.querySelector(".my-container")
        menu_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            sidebar.classList.toggle("active-nav")
            container.classList.toggle("active-cont")
        })
    </script>
    <!-- custom js start -->    
<!-- Sidebar code end -->

<!-- Body block container format start -->
    <div class="container">
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock body %}
    </div>
<!-- Body block container format end -->

<!-- Javascript start -->
    <script src="/static/js/base.js"></script>
<!-- Javascript start -->    
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the styles css file that starts with the topbar, then the sidebar is there too, this is where I got stuck in isolating the two from each other.

**styles.css**

```
.send-button {
    background: #54C7C3;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 25px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.g-button {
    color: #fff !important;
    border: 1px solid #EA4335;
    background: #ea4335 !important;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 25px;
}

.my-input {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor: text;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    transition: border .1s linear;
}

.header-title {
    margin: 5rem 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 31px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #4c5357;
}

h2 {
    color: #5e8396;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.login-or {
    position: relative;
    color: #aaa;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.span-or {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -2px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.hr-or {
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 26px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}

.container .form-1 {
    width: 25rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3rem 0 0 22rem;

}


/* Sidebar section */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -300px;
    background-color: #7952b3;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

.nav-link:active,
.nav-link:focus,
.nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff26;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #7952b3;
}

.dropdown-item:active,
.dropdown-item:focus,
.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff26;
}

.my-container {
    transition: 0.4s;
}


/* for navbar */

.active-nav {
    margin-left: 0;
}


/* for main section */

.active-cont {
    margin-left: 250px;
}

#menu-btn {
    background-color: #7952b3;
    color: #fff;
}

#menu-btn:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem #7952b344;
}
```

Comment: Media-queries should always be listed **after** the basic rules of the css.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov, you mean I need to move the sidebar code at the top instead?

Comment: Anything after your media request should be listed above. Media queries should be last. Otherwise, there will be an overlap of the css rules.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov can you show me how please, I did try move the media query to the bottom, but still the general css style is applied to the sidebar too

Comment: My advice regarding media queries is not a solution to your problem. This is just a remark.